# How to increase the column width dynamically in iReport using dynamic report?

Tags: jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I have created a jrxml file and by using dynamic reports I am filling up the data for the template.I need to adjust the column width based on the content inside it,I have looked into documentation and blogs everything leads to stretch overflow.But it will only increase the height and wrap the data .

My scenario I need to adjust the width of the column based on the content.Is it possible anyway? Is it possible to do it by using `DynamicReports`? If so how?

Answer (score 1):

In jasper reports, you cannot increase the width of the component dynamically. You can only increase the height dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

In dynamicreport also you have set width of column , it not increase on text length,pl check this link,may be helpful to you.
[DynamicReport](http://www.dynamicreports.org/examples/examples-overview#column)